# How do I get control over my character back?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I'm stuck at BM:AC where Ras al gul keeps Talia under siege to provoke batman.

But I'm stuck at that scene. I can only move my camera, all other controls are gone.

I can acess the main menu, but the gameplay is stuck. What can I do so I can play on?

My PC has a HP core2 Duo, 4GB ram, 512 Nvidia gt9000 graphics.

Comment: If Ras is threatening to kill Talia, then the game should've told you which button to press in order to use the Reverse Batarang. Maybe you didn't notice the message, or the message bugged out.

Comment: Yes. That was what my friends said was supposed to happen. I tried re-installing the game but the bug persisted.

Answer (score 1):

Is the screen where you get a new gadget(reverse batarang) even displayed to you?Or the buttons to use it?

On PC reverse batarang should be:  hold right mouse(to ready batarang) + hold middle mouse(to lock on target) + release right mose(to throw)

In case you really encountered the bug like [these people](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/982135-batman-arkham-city/answers?qid=306672) try lowering details and playing this part in windowed screen.

Comment: Not any controls are visible only the characters camera movement using mouse is possible @Arremer